# CSS Img resize transition time only on hover

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I'm having an issue with an animation on one of my images. I want the image to resize on hover with a transition time (and then have a transition time back to the original size when the mouse moves off the image) but then when i resize the window and the image resizes accordingly, it resizes with the transition time . Does anyone  know a way to get around this?

```
<div class="column">
    <a href="-----.html">
        <img src="-----.jpg">
    </a>
</div>

.column img{
    filter: brightness(0.8);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    width:100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 300px);
}

.column:hover img{
    filter: brightness(0.5);
    width:110%;
    transform: translate(-5%,-5%);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    height: calc(110vh - 300px);
}
```

I can see why the transition applies to the image when the window resizes, but i don't know how else to get the transition to apply when the mouse moves away. Can anyone suggest a way around this?

[Gif of resizing issue](https://gyazo.com/4830a6d6f0014147bbe5130f82a05ef3)

edit: full code posted below

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


/*Header*/

header {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #F89828;
  height: 159px;
}

header img {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 122px);
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  height: 39px;
  width: 244px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(100vh - 239px);
}

.row .column img {
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  height: calc(100vh - 239px);
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.row .column:hover img {
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  width: 110%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-5%, -5%);
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  height: calc(110vh - 239px);
}

.centered {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*footer*/

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #808080;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100/?random">
  </header>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a href="---.html">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random">
        <div class="centered">1</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="---.html">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random" />
        <div class="centered">2</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>This is where I would put some filler text, if I had any</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean the width of he image is 100% of the window (or the column) when not hovering? That part is not clear from the question.

Comment: yes when not hovering the image should be 100% of the column. I have tried another users answer of defining the width when not hovering and this has helped but now the image is going through the transition for height. I have since added a footer of fixed height to the page so i am now using height: calc(100vh - 300px); to define height. could this be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the transition on your image only when the window is hovered. This way, on resize it won't affect your element anymore, but on your element's hover and mouseout it will still be active.

```css
/* when hovering the page */
:hover .row .column img {
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.row .column img {
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  height: calc(80vh - 10px);
  /*  transition: 0.6s ease; [removed]*/
}

.row .column:hover img {
  /*  transition: 0.6s ease; [useless]*/
  width: 110%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-5%, -5%);
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  height: calc(80vh - 10px);
}

.column {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(60vh - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="---.html">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random">
      <div class="centered">1</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="---.html">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random" />
      <div class="centered">2</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But using this solution, if *mousing-out* from the document itself, then the transition will also get disabled...

Unfortunately, I don't see any other solution than that, except using js of course.

```js
(function(){
  let timer;
  const docEl = document.documentElement;
  addEventListener('resize', e => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    docEl.classList.add('resizing');
    timer = setTimeout(_ => docEl.classList.remove('resizing'), 200);
  });
})();
```

```css
:root.resizing .row .column img {
  transition: none;
}
.row .column img {
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  height: calc(80vh - 10px);
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.row .column:hover img {
  width: 110%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-5%, -5%);
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  height: calc(80vh - 10px);
}

.column {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(60vh - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="---.html">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random">
      <div class="centered">1</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="---.html">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random" />
      <div class="centered">2</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `width` without `hover` for animation on mouse out, check it

```css
.column img{
    filter: brightness(0.8);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    width:35%;
}

.column:hover img{
    filter: brightness(0.5);
    width:110%;
    transform: translate(-5%,-5%);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <a href="-----.html">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The transition on :hover is redundant in this example.

Comment: I just tried that with width 100% but it still has the same issue. I have since added a height constraint but its not helping either.  i know this will change the aspect ratio but at the moment im more concerned with the transition..

Comment: Beacuse of translate and width both applying on hover so, Remove translate and check

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scale(2)` it's working well for me.

> But you need to change `translate()` *value* as per the `scale()` *value* as per your requirement.

```css
.column img{
    filter: brightness(0.8);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.column:hover img{
    filter: brightness(0.5);
    transform: translate(50%,50%) scale(2);
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <a href="-----.html">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random">
    </a>
</div>
```

**Updated with your code.**

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


/*Header*/

header {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #F89828;
  height: 159px;
}

header img {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 122px);
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  height: 39px;
  width: 244px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(100vh - 239px);
}

.row .column img {
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  height: calc(100vh - 239px);
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.row .column:hover img {
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  width: 110%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-10%,-10%) scale(1.3);
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  height: calc(110vh - 239px);
}


.centered {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*footer*/

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #808080;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100/?random">
  </header>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a href="---.html">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random">
        <div class="centered">1</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="---.html">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100/?random" />
        <div class="centered">2</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>This is where I would put some filler text, if I had any</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: This worked great to stop the resizing transition! the only issue now is when the window is narrow enough, the images do not reach the top of the footer. I think it might be an issue with me using height: calc(100vh - 300px);

Comment: It can be, also please tweak the `translate()` as per your requirement.

Comment: Just updated with the full code, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  display:     inline-block;
  width:       64px;
  height:      64px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.icon, .icon-one, .icon-two{
  position:   absolute;
 
  transition: all .5s;
  transform-style:     preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
   width:50px;
      height:50px;

}


}
.icon-wrap .icon-one{

 width:150px;
      height:150px;
transform:translate(0%,0%);}

/* ::: HOVER EFFECTS (Remove Automated for this to work) */

.icon-wrap:hover .icon{ transform: translate(0%,0%); }

/* ::: AUTOMATED EFFECTS */

.icon-wrap .icon{
  animation: icon-wrap 5s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: icon-wrap 5s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}



@keyframes icon-wrap {
  0% { transform:translate(0%,0%); }
  100% { transform: translate(40%,40%)scale(2);
   width:150px;
      height:150px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes icon-wrap {
  0% { transform: translate(0%,0%); }
  100% { transform: translate(40%,40%) scale(2); 
   width:150px;
      height:150px;  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container icon-wrap">
<div class="icon">
   <div class="icon-one">
    <a href="-----.html">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display:     inline-block;
  width:       64px;
  height:      64px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.icon, .icon-one, .icon-two{
  position:   absolute;
 
  transition: all .5s;
  transform-style:     preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
   width:50px;
      height:50px;

}


}
.icon-wrap .icon-one{

 width:150px;
      height:150px;
transform:translate(40%,40%)scale(2);}

/* ::: HOVER EFFECTS (Remove Automated for this to work) */

.icon-wrap:hover .icon{ transform: translate(40%,40%)scale(2); }

/* ::: AUTOMATED EFFECTS */

.icon-wrap .icon{
  animation: icon-wrap 5s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: icon-wrap 5s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container icon-wrap">
<div class="icon">
   <div class="icon-one">
    <a href="-----.html">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as i can see, this code snippet just pulses between the larger and smaller states no matter where my mouse is positioned.

Comment: It depends on the timer. If you need when you move the mouse, I will change it.