# set transition to none during resizing

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to deactivate all transitions during resizing. Cause when I resize screen, card and other elements move slowly to their new positions and it looks really bad

i got this css code in sass

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  menu();
  resize();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  resize();
})



function menu(){
   $("#open-menu").click(function(){
      $("#mobile-menu div div").animate({"width":"100%"});
      $("#mobile-menu").css("z-index", "10");
      $("#menu-options").css("display","flex");
   });


   $("#close-menu").click(function(){
      $("#mobile-menu div div").animate({"width":"0%"});
      $("#mobile-menu").css("z-index", "-10");
      $("#menu-options").css("display","none");
      
   });
}



function resize(){
   var card = $("#card img").height();
   $("#card").css("height", card+"px");
   $("body").css("transition", "0s");
}
```

```css
* {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 html {
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
 body .container {
     width: 90%;
     max-width: 1920px;
     margin: auto;
}
 body h1, body h2, body h3, body h4, body h5, body h6 {
     font-family: Domine, serif;
}
 body p, body a {
     font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 body ul {
     list-style: none;
}
 header {
     position: fixed;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     padding-top: 30px;
     padding-bottom: 30px;
     background: #ffffff;
     z-index: 100;
     box-shadow: #ecf0f1 1px 0 3px;
}
 header .container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
}
 header .container a {
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     color: #000;
}
 header .container input {
     display: none;
}
 header .container #open-menu, header .container #close-menu {
     display: none;
}
 header .container nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     padding-right: 20px;
}
 header .container nav ul li:last-child {
     padding-right: 0;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     header .container #open-menu {
         display: block;
    }
     header .container input:checked ~ #open-menu {
         display: none;
    }
     header .container input:checked ~ #close-menu {
         display: block;
    }
     header .container input:checked ~ .about {
         background: red;
    }
     header .container nav {
         display: none;
    }
}
 .about {
     height: 100vh;
     position: relative;
     margin-top: 50px;
}
 .about .container {
     height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     align-items: center;
}
 .about .container .img-container {
     width: 35%;
}
 .about .container .img-container #card {
     position: relative;
     width: 80%;
     transition: all 0.7s linear;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
 .about .container .img-container #card:hover {
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
 .about .container .img-container #card img {
     border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 10;
     border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30%/30% 30% 70% 70%;
     left: 0;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translate(0%, -50%);
     z-index: 5;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
}
 .about .container .img-container #card .social {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     z-index: 3;
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
 .about .container .img-container #card .social ul li {
     padding-right: 20px;
     display: inline-block;
}
 .about .container .img-container #card .social ul li:last-child {
     padding-right: 0;
}
 .about .container .img-container #card .social ul li a {
     color: #053f5e;
     font-size: 2rem;
     transition: 0.5s;
}
 .about .container .img-container #card .social ul li a:hover {
     color: #95a5a6;
}
 .about .container .description {
     width: 65%;
}
 .about .container .description h2 {
     padding-bottom: 20px;
     font-size: 2rem;
}
 .about .container .description p {
     text-align: justify;
     font-size: 1.2rem;
     margin-bottom: 40px;
}
 .about .container .description a {
     padding: 10px 50px;
     border: 2px solid #ffd700;
     position: relative;
     color: #000;
     border-radius: 20px;
     font-size: 1rem;
}
 .about .container .description a::before {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     width: 0;
     content: "";
     height: 100%;
     background: #ffd700;
     transition: 0.5s;
     z-index: -10;
     border-radius: 18px;
}
 .about .container .description a:hover::before {
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 18px;
}
 .mobile-menu {
     position: fixed;
     display: flex;
     z-index: -10;
     height: 100vh;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
}
 .mobile-menu div {
     width: 20%;
}
 .mobile-menu div div {
     width: 0%;
     height: 100vh;
     background: #022c43;
}
 .mobile-menu .menu-options {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     background: transparent;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 100;
     display: none;
     overflow: auto;
}
 .mobile-menu .menu-options ul {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding-right: 40px;
     padding-left: 40px;
}
 .mobile-menu .menu-options ul li {
     padding-top: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
 .mobile-menu .menu-options ul li a {
     color: #000;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .about .container {
         margin-top: 120px;
    }
     .about .container .img-container {
         width: 100%;
    }
     .about .container .img-container #card {
         margin: auto;
         transform-style: flat;
    }
     .about .container .img-container #card:hover {
         transform: none;
    }
     .about .container .description {
         width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Domine|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/effects.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c3e042a20b.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
            <label for="menu" id="open-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
            <label for="menu" id="close-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="about">
        <div class="mobile-menu" id="mobile-menu">
            <div class="menu-options" id="menu-options">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div><div><a href=""></a></div></div>
            <div><div><a href=""></a></div></div>
            <div><div><a href=""></a></div></div>
            <div><div><a href=""></a></div></div>
            <div><div><a href=""></a></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="img-container">
                <div id="card">
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1d/1c/3d/1d1c3d3d35e2d14d2fdef598d572098e--men-haircuts--best-mens-haircuts.jpg" alt="" class="front">
                    <div class="social back">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h2 class="description-title">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem deserunt numquam et reprehenderit, nobis eligendi asperiores quasi animi error eius nam sed aliquam dolorum adipisci incidunt ex assumenda nulla.Minus quae optio illo esse numquam perferendis aperiam veritatis unde repellendus dolorum non, architecto ipsum iusto eaque excepturi assumenda officiis aut ducimus quasi ab eum, ut nostrum rem obcaecati. Beatae.</p>
                <a href="" id="see-more">Ver mas</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to avoid that behavior by jquery

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
      resize();
    })


    function resize(){
       $("body").css("transition", 0);
}
```

also tried

```
$("body").css("transition", "none");
$("body").css("transition", "0s");
```

But it doesn't work, how could I solve this ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Img resize transition time only on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215568/css-img-resize-transition-time-only-on-hover)

Comment: Have you tried applying the css method on the #card element which actually contains the transition?

Comment: Can you post a runnable snippet which shows the issue you are facing. Then it will be easier for us to fix.

Comment: Hello I have added snipped, please notice the image movement during resizing

Answer (score -1):

In CSS `.about .container .img-container #card` change
`transition: all 0.7s linear`
to
`transition: transform 0.7s linear`

And remove `$("body").css("transition", "0s");` from your JS as it's useless.
See the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  menu();
  resize();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  resize();
})



function menu() {
  $("#open-menu").click(function() {
    $("#mobile-menu div div").animate({
      "width": "100%"
    });
    $("#mobile-menu").css("z-index", "10");
    $("#menu-options").css("display", "flex");
  });


  $("#close-menu").click(function() {
    $("#mobile-menu div div").animate({
      "width": "0%"
    });
    $("#mobile-menu").css("z-index", "-10");
    $("#menu-options").css("display", "none");

  });
}



function resize() {
  var card = $("#card img").height();
  $("#card").css("height", card + "px");
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body .container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
}

body h1,
body h2,
body h3,
body h4,
body h5,
body h6 {
  font-family: Domine, serif;
}

body p,
body a {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: #ecf0f1 1px 0 3px;
}

header .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header .container a {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #000;
}

header .container input {
  display: none;
}

header .container #open-menu,
header .container #close-menu {
  display: none;
}

header .container nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

header .container nav ul li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header .container #open-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  header .container input:checked~#open-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  header .container input:checked~#close-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  header .container input:checked~.about {
    background: red;
  }
  header .container nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

.about {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.about .container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.about .container .img-container {
  width: 35%;
}

.about .container .img-container #card {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.about .container .img-container #card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.about .container .img-container #card img {
  border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30%/30% 30% 70% 70%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  z-index: 5;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.about .container .img-container #card .social {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.about .container .img-container #card .social ul li {
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.about .container .img-container #card .social ul li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.about .container .img-container #card .social ul li a {
  color: #053f5e;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.about .container .img-container #card .social ul li a:hover {
  color: #95a5a6;
}

.about .container .description {
  width: 65%;
}

.about .container .description h2 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.about .container .description p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.about .container .description a {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: 2px solid #ffd700;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.about .container .description a::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffd700;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: -10;
  border-radius: 18px;
}

.about .container .description a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 18px;
}

.mobile-menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -10;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.mobile-menu div {
  width: 20%;
}

.mobile-menu div div {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #022c43;
}

.mobile-menu .menu-options {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mobile-menu .menu-options ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.mobile-menu .menu-options ul li {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.mobile-menu .menu-options ul li a {
  color: #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .about .container {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
  .about .container .img-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .about .container .img-container #card {
    margin: auto;
    transform-style: flat;
  }
  .about .container .img-container #card:hover {
    transform: none;
  }
  .about .container .description {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Domine|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/effects.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c3e042a20b.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
      <label for="menu" id="open-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
      <label for="menu" id="close-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="about">
    <div class="mobile-menu" id="mobile-menu">
      <div class="menu-options" id="menu-options">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img-container">
        <div id="card">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1d/1c/3d/1d1c3d3d35e2d14d2fdef598d572098e--men-haircuts--best-mens-haircuts.jpg" alt="" class="front">
          <div class="social back">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></span></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></span></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h2 class="description-title">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem deserunt numquam et reprehenderit, nobis eligendi asperiores quasi animi error eius nam sed aliquam dolorum adipisci incidunt ex assumenda nulla.Minus quae optio illo esse numquam
          perferendis aperiam veritatis unde repellendus dolorum non, architecto ipsum iusto eaque excepturi assumenda officiis aut ducimus quasi ab eum, ut nostrum rem obcaecati. Beatae.</p>
        <a href="" id="see-more">Ver mas</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```